# Pagination with array in yii2

Tags: php, view, pagination, yii2

I want to use pagination in my view, but I can't figure out how to do it in conjunction with the `find()` method.

Getting the numbers of pages works correctly, but it always displays all values from the database. I want to see 15 comments per page.

Here is my ViewAction controller:

```php
 public function actionView($id) {
     $query = UrComment::find()->where(['IsDeleted' => 0]);

     $pagination = new Pagination(['totalCount' => $query->count(), 'pageSize'=>12]);
     return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findOneModel($id),
            'comment' => UrComment::findComment($id),
            'pagination'=> $pagination
     ]);
}
```

And this is how I get the comments:

```php
public static function findComment($id)
{
    if (($model = UrUser::findOne($id)) !== null) {
        $Id=$model->Id;
        $comment = UrComment::find()->where(['Rel_User' => $Id])->all();
        return $comment;
    } else {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }
}
```

I tried to use this:

```php
public function actionView($id) {
    $query = UrComment::find()->where(['IsDeleted' => 0]);
    $pagination = new Pagination(['totalCount' => $query->count(), 'pageSize'=>12]);
    $comment= UrComment::findComment($id);
    $comment->offset($pagination->offset)
        ->limit($pagination->limit)
        ->all();

    return $this->render('view', [
                'model' => $this->findOneModel($id),
                'comment' =>$comment,
                'pagination'=> $pagination
    ]);
}
```

But I get this error:

> Call to a member function offset() on array

Then I display it in the view:

```php
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\DetailView;
use yii\helpers\Url;
/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model backend\modules\users\models\UrUser */

$this->title = $model->Name;
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => Yii::t('app', 'Użytkownicy'), 'url' => ['index']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="ur-user-view">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <p>
        <?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Aktualizuj'), ['update', 'id' => $model->Id], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
        <?=
        Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Usuń'), ['delete', 'id' => $model->Id], [
            'class' => 'btn btn-danger',
            'data' => [
                'confirm' => Yii::t('app', 'Jesteś pewien, że chesz usunąć tego użytkownika?'),
                'method' => 'post',
            ],
        ])
        ?>
    </p>

    <?=
    DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attributes' => [
            'Id',
            'Name',
            'Surname',
            'BirthDate',
            'Login',
            'Email:email',
            ['attribute' => 'Rel_Sex', 'value' => (isset($model->relSex->Name)? $model->relSex->Name : "Nie wybrano")],
            ['attribute' => 'Rel_Language', 'value' => (isset($model->relLanguage->Name)) ? $model->relLanguage->Name : "Nie wybrano"],
            ['attribute' => 'Rel_Country', 'value' => (isset($model->relCountry->Name)) ? $model->relCountry->Name : "Nie wybrano"],
            ['attribute' => 'Rel_Category', 'value' => (isset($model->relUserCategory->Name)) ? $model->relUserCategory->Name : "Nie wybrano"],
        ],
    ])
    ?>

Komentarze użytkownika: <?= $model->Name.' '.$model->Surname;?><br><br>


    <?php foreach ($comment as $comm): ?>

     <?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Edytuj'), ['update-user-comment', 'id' => $comm->Id], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
        <?=
        Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Usuń'), ['delete-comment', 'id' => $comm->Id], [
            'class' => 'btn btn-danger',
            'data' => [
                'confirm' => Yii::t('app', 'Jesteś pewien, że chesz usunąć tego użytkownika?'),
                'method' => 'post',
            ],
        ])
        ?>
            <p><?= $comm->Text ?></p>

    <hr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php
   echo \yii\widgets\LinkPager::widget([
    'pagination' => $pagination,
]);
?>

</div>
</div>    
</div>
```

---

How can I limit the `UrComment::findComment($id)` using the pagination?

EDIT:

I think I understand you, and I think I've done everything you told me in your answer, but now I have another problem. I need to display under view comments only that which is id view only this one person not all comments.

Here is what I have now:

ActionView:

```php
public function actionView($id) {
    $searchModel = new CommentSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    $dataProvider->query->andWhere(['IsDeleted' => 0]);
    $dataProvider->pagination->pageSize=15;

    return $this->render('view', [
                'model' => $this->findOneModel($id),
                'comment' => UrComment::findComment($id),
                'searchModel' => $searchModel,
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

CommentSearch:

```php
<?php

namespace backend\modules\users\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use common\models\UrComment;

class CommentSearch extends UrComment
{        
    public function rules() {
        return [
            [['Id'], 'integer'],
            [['Text'], 'safe'],           
        ];
    }

    public function scenarios() {
        // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
        return Model::scenarios();
    }

    public function search($params) {
        $query = UrComment::find();

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'Id' => $this->Id,
            'Text' => $this->Text,                
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'Text', $this->Text]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

View:

```php
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\DetailView;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use yii\widgets\ListView;
/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model backend\modules\users\models\UrUser */

$this->title = $model->Name;
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => Yii::t('app', 'Użytkownicy'), 'url' => ['index']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="ur-user-view">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <p>
        <?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Aktualizuj'), ['update', 'id' => $model->Id], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
        <?=
        Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Usuń'), ['delete', 'id' => $model->Id], [
            'class' => 'btn btn-danger',
            'data' => [
                'confirm' => Yii::t('app', 'Jesteś pewien, że chesz usunąć tego użytkownika?'),
                'method' => 'post',
            ],
        ])
        ?>
    </p>

    <?=
    DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attributes' => [
            'Id',
            'Name',
            'Surname',
            'BirthDate',
            'Login',
            'Email:email',
            ['attribute' => 'Rel_Sex', 'value' => (isset($model->relSex->Name)? $model->relSex->Name : "Nie wybrano")],
            ['attribute' => 'Rel_Language', 'value' => (isset($model->relLanguage->Name)) ? $model->relLanguage->Name : "Nie wybrano"],
            ['attribute' => 'Rel_Country', 'value' => (isset($model->relCountry->Name)) ? $model->relCountry->Name : "Nie wybrano"],
            ['attribute' => 'Rel_Category', 'value' => (isset($model->relUserCategory->Name)) ? $model->relUserCategory->Name : "Nie wybrano"],
        ],
    ])
    ?>
Komentarze użytkownika: <?= $model->Name.' '.$model->Surname;?><br><br>
<?php    
  echo ListView::widget([
   'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
   'itemView' => 'comments',
   'viewParams' => ['comment' => $comment, 'model'=>$model],
]);
?>
</div>
</div> 
</div>
```

And my item comments:

```php
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\DetailView;
use yii\helpers\Url;
/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model backend\modules\users\models\UrUser */


?> 
     <?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Edytuj'), ['update-user-comment', 'id' => $comment->Id], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
        <?=
        Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Usuń'), ['delete-comment', 'id' => $comment->Id], [
            'class' => 'btn btn-danger',
            'data' => [
                'confirm' => Yii::t('app', 'Jesteś pewien, że chesz usunąć tego użytkownika?'),
                'method' => 'post',
            ],
        ])
        ?>
            <p><?= $comment->Text ?></p>

    <hr>
```

Using that code, now I have error that in this item in button edit:

> $comment->Id], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
>
> Trying to get property of non-object

And I can't use foreach there because I have duplicate comments. Should change something in comment Search or in my function `findComment(id)` inquiry?

There is my actual item 'comments' where I want to display text of comments and buttons to edit and delete comment. But this does not work for me. I have:

> Use of undefined constant Id - assumed 'Id'

and

> Use of undefined constant Text - assumed 'Text';

```php
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\DetailView;
use yii\helpers\Url;
/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model backend\modules\users\models\UrUser */


?> 
     <?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Edytuj'), ['update-user-comment', 'id' => Id], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
        <?=
        Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Usuń'), ['delete-comment', 'id' => Id], [
            'class' => 'btn btn-danger',
            'data' => [
                'confirm' => Yii::t('app', 'Jesteś pewien, że chesz usunąć tego użytkownika?'),
                'method' => 'post',
            ],
        ])
        ?>
            <p><?= Text ?></p>
    <hr>
```

Comment: This has a bad title. I came to find out how to paginate an array instead of an ActiveQuery - but it's only an ActiveQuery...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use model and foreach in not easy, use pagination because pagination if base on dataProvider and not directly for model ..

Essentially finding the model like you did mean work direclty on the data while pagination don't work directly on the data but rather use the a sql query for retrive information from db a let these available to  widgets .. this is what the dataProvider perform ..  .. then I suggest you of use a widget like ListView and change your query based on a find with a dataProvider based on a modelSearch  ..

```
public function actionView($id) {
    $searchModel = new UrCommentSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    $dataProvider->query->andWhere(['IsDeleted' => 0]);
    $dataProvider->pagination->pageSize=15;

    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $this->findOneModel($id),
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
```

and for view.php

```
<?php 

echo ' <h1>User :  ' .  $model->userName . '</h1>';

echo '<h2>Comments</h2'>,

echo ListView::widget([

   'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
   'itemView' => '_comment',
]);
```

where _comment is a partial view of you comment layout  .,.

then in  _comment.php you can simply

```
<?=$model->id;?> 
<?=$model->text;?>
```

Comment: Thanks You for Your comment. You entered me to this solution but i still dont know how to transfer my comments belonging to the user into Comments(item view) where i display this comments

Comment: You can  pass both  ($model for user data and $dataProvider for comments ) and then display model in a proper top area and the comments in  ListView  ..  I have update answer with some suggestion in this way  ..

Comment: but $model concerns users table. U write tihs itemView but i dont know what i should write in this _comment to display this comments. Where I should used the this $dataProvider in view to display coments or this query in $dataProvider

Comment: can u look at my last code when u will have time? Becouse when I used  Text; its no work for me. Could it not convey it with the dataProvider? I serach for examples but i fail. What is the way to display the comments from query becouse simple Id(with big first letter becosue in dataBase i have big Letter first) or simple Text is not work for me and i dont know why